# python + django web developement using Xcode5 IDE on mavericks OSX 10.9

Tags: python, django, macos, xcode5

I want to do python Web developement using Django framework.

1) Does Xcode5 support web developement using python and django?

2) If yes, how to setup the environment on OSX 10.9 Mavericks and start developing.

3) If no, Which are open source alternatives on mac.

if you have any suggestion or solutions please share it. It will be really appreciated.
It will be really helpful to proceed further.

Comment: it doesn't really matter what IDE you use - as long as it supports python you can build a django app on it. I use sublime text tho if you're curious

Comment: Thanks Cole, Please can you guide me to getting started with it and set up environment on maverick.

Comment: I would just use the django installation guide - you basically just install the packages on your system and any django stuff you do will be built around that  follow the tutorial or documentation if you're stuck at first https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/install/